# Help me to identify this bike

Tags: identify-this-bike

**Can someone help me to identify this bike model and where can I find it?**
[image]

Comment: Have you seen it for real? If so can you get a picture of the headtube badge? If not, what's the source?

Comment: Not, I haven't seen for real. I found the picture months ago on Pinterest :/

Comment: Google Image Search is your best friend for searches like this.  Give it a try, the answers appear to be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's one of [State Bicycle Co.'s city bike models](https://www.statebicycle.com/collections/city-bikes-1).

Found via a quick Google reverse image search. That particular image showed up on an Amazon page for the front and rear baskets, also made by State Bicycle.

They have a [store locator](https://www.statebicycle.com/pages/bike-store-locator) on their website.

Comment: Be aware that it might not be road legal everywhere. From the picture it seems to have a back-pedalling rear brake only and no front brake. Many legislations require two independent brakes.

Comment: True @Carel in 2015 we saw a flood of Chinese made "City bikes" they called them. They're a dime a dozen in China to the point where sadly a greedy rent to ride system has made them disposable. So someone started pushing marketing over here, I suspect.